# Facebook "Like Button" Linking to wrong page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know I am behind the curve on facebook.  I am trying to create "Like" buttons that are behind a login but link to publicly view-able pages. The problem is most of the time the button isn't linking directly to the page but to the login page.  The page is dynamic so I am not sure if that is part of the issue but sometimes the links are corrent and sometimes not.

Below are two links that link to the same page but bring up different "like" links.  The second one seems to link to the www.domain.com and NOT to the actual page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.domain.com/facebook/index.cfm/show_shareRecap/eventGuid_a563d56d-de24-4219-9da7-78a46c4ab43a/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.domain.com/facebook/index.cfm/show_shareRecap/eventGuid_8d354988-ad44-4608-8d4f-54be7dacdeb9/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

The only other FB scripts that I have on the page are:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) { 
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong It would be much appreciated!

Comment: "two links that link to the same page" ... those links don't point to the same URL.

Comment: Correct, two seperate URLs but its one page the index page that pulls dynamic content and I didn't know if that might be affecting the way facebook links since it works sometime but not others

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see what exactly Facebook sees when scraping your URLs.

Comment: It would help if you provide the urls in question

Comment: @CBroe I thought I has this working by removing the canonical tag since this is what the debugger said was wrong.  NOW it turns out that if I view the link page in the facebook debugger it works but if I add a "Like" button to a page that I haven't run through the debugger I have the original problem of the "Like" linking to www.domain.com instead of the specific page that I want.  IF however I then send the page URL through the facebook debug page it works fine without actually changing anything on the page.

Comment: Evidently this is a known issue with Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/396236587087190

Answer (score 1):

Do you have OG tags for the website and OG tags for the Like button object? If so this could be your issue.

Comment: I think I have them set correctly (or at least according to the debugger I do)  Here is a link to the page and it appears to be correct as of now http://www.proscoutvip.com/facebook/index.cfm/show_shareRecap/eventGuid_a3d62116-ccb1-4d09-a096-84ec60d73b96/